# Firebase doc author in StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter

I'm building a shopping app, and I have a collection to store all the users orders. I want to show the user his orders only! but I wanna use `StreamBuilder`.

I'm trying to do this in the stream part:

```
stream: Firestore.instance.collection('orders').where('author'==user.uid).snapshots(),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/where.html), the `where` function takes in a positional argument for the field, and has several named arguments. One of those is `isEqualTo`.

Try the following instead:

```
stream: Firestore.instance.collection('orders').where('author', isEqualTo: user.uid).snapshots(),
```